# Keeping the excel opened before it completely refreshed through powershell?

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I am using this powershell script to open an excel, run a macro to refresh all, save and close.
This is working fine but the excel is saving and closing before refreshing the excel completely.
Is there a way i can add a wait statement so that it can wait until the workbook is completely refreshed.

```
$objectExcel = new-object -c excel.application
$objectExcel.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
$objectExcel.visible = $True;
#$objectExcel.visible = $True;
$Classeur = $objectExcel.workbooks.open("\\gbrmiteufs01.eu.xerox.net\SWG01\XOG-BORG\EBIP\POS Data\POS 
Data.xlsm", $null, $false)
$objectExcel.run("Workbook_RefreshAll")
$objectExcel.run("RemoveODBC") # another custom macro for removing data connecion
$Classeur.save()
$Classeur.close()
$objectExcel.quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried turning off the "refresh in background" for your queries?

Comment: i did not make any change in default settings, let me check it please.